# XPages Domino search producing incorrect results for one particular search term

Tags: javascript, search, xpages, lotus-domino

I have a large domino database that I am searching with some very basic syntax:
[LastName] CONTAINS "Name or first letter or letters of name to search for"*

Specific example:
[LastName] CONTAINS R* 
This returns all lastnames that start with "R".

This works very well on any letter except for "S".  If you just search for all lastnames beginning with "S", you will only get a very small result which is wrong.  If the query is further qualified by a location it will return 0 results.
[LastName] CONTAINS S* AND [Campus] CONTAINS 101
Returns 0 results which I know is not true.

However, [LastName] CONTAINS Se* AND [Campus] CONTAINS 101 will return all the lastnames at Campus 101 that begin with Se.  [LastName] CONTAINS Se* will return the correct results.

This happens with both the FirstName and the LastName fields.  Other fields do not display this anomaly.  Could there be a corrupt record?  If so, is it possible to isolate it?

Thanks,
---Lisa&

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full text search in Domino doesn't work reliable for **one** letter.

Use `search()` instead with a formula like:

```
@Begins(LastName; "R") & @Contains(Campus; "101")
```

[SSJS search()](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_domino_Database_search.html?lang=en) would be:

```
var searchFormula = 'Begins(LastName; "R") & @Contains(Campus; "101")';
var dc:NotesDocumentCollection = database.search(searchFormula);
```

Use NotesDocumentCollection to show relevant fields (including links to documents) in a repeat control.

Comment: And if you can use it, I believe creating a NoteCollection of data documents also performs much quicker than a search. It needs Domino 9.0.x I believe (I had problems with NoteCollection methods when trying to port OpenNTF Domino API back to 8.5.3 a few years ago). NoteCollection is what's used extensively for OpenNTF Domino API graph functionality.

Comment: First problem:  I created a small database of names.  8 records to be exact. Two of the Lastnames (Field named Lastname) start with "F". I added a button to an xpage and when I use the code:

Comment: var searchFormula = 'Begins(FirstName; "F") ';
var dc:NotesDocumentCollection = database.search(searchFormula);

Comment: The easiest way would probably to stay with viewPanel/search and to force users to enter at least three letters for name.

Comment: Knut, You are correct - but I am hoping to learn something new.

Comment: You have Lastname fields starting with "F" but you test for Firstname in your formula...

Comment: ... and it has to be @Begins with @ before Begins.

Comment: Thanks to Knut's help, I was able to learn a new way of searching.  Today (after much research) I managed to display the results of the search using a repeat control.  Now to see if it helps with the "S" (one letter) problem.

Comment: I like this search.  But, I need it to work with a variable so the user can enter the search term.    I want to be able to code term = "userentry" and put that in the search instead of specifying "101" or "R" etc.  I thought it would be easy, but cannot find the correct syntax.

Comment: `var searchFormula` is just a string. So add constant and variable parts together like `var searchFormula = 'Begins(LastName; "'+ beginLastNameVariable + '") & @Contains(Campus; "' + campusVariable + '")';`

Comment: Beautiful, works with scoped variables as well.  I do think that creating a NotesDocumentCollection is faster than searching a view.  But, my observation is not based on any metrics.  Thanks again.